# Как пользоваться %rowtype при вставке в таблицу с identity колонкой?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

В БД есть таблицы, у которых много колонок, но выглядят они где-то так:

```
create table t1 (id number primary key, memo varchar2 (4000));
create sequence seqt1 nocache;
```

Вставка в таблицы:

```
declare
    r t1%rowtype;
begin
    r.id := seqt1.nextval; 
    r.memo := 'first row';
    insert into t1 values r;
end;
/
```

работает:

```
        ID MEMO      
---------- ----------
         1 first row
```

С переходом на 12c первичный ключ будет выглядеть так:

```
drop table t1;    
create table t1 (id number generated always as identity primary key, memo varchar2 (4000));
```

Но предыдущий код вставки с закоментированной строчкой `r.id := seqt1.nextval;`, даёт ошибку:

> ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column

Как быть в этом случае?

Comment: Вопрос с переносом ответа со связанной [темы на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675304/how-to-use-rowtype-when-inserting-into-oracle-table-with-identity-column/53656475#53656475). Если есть другoе решениe (а таковые точно есть), предлагайте, отмечу как принятый, если оно действительно полезней.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться представлением, где идентификатор объявлен как "невидимый" столбец ([подробнее о *invisible*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAGDBIC)). Как-то так:

```
create table t1 (id number generated always as identity primary key, memo varchar2 (4000))
;
create or replace view viewt1 (id invisible, memo) as select * from t1
; 
<<my>> declare 
    r viewt1%rowtype;   
    id number;
begin
    r.memo := 'first row';
    insert into viewt1 values r
    returning id into my.id
    ;
    dbms_output.put_line ('inserted '||sql%rowcount||' row(s) id='||id);  
end;
/
```

> inserted 1 row(s) id=1