# AUTO_INCREMENT и SEQUENCE в разных SQL диалектах

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, autoincrement

Почему, например, в Oracle SQL нет понятия `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Я так понимаю, для реализации инкриметного ключа в Oracle используется `SEQUENCE`.

Но почему этот способ более универсальный и в чем плюсы и минусы использования `SEQUENCE` по сравнеию с `AUTO_INCREMENT`? Почему Oracle пошла по этому пути?

Comment: в 12с есть понятие `identity` (как в sql server, что есть аналог `auto_increment`)

Comment: @teran можете сформулировать своё овтет и написать ниже, чтобы я мог поставить ему отметку, как лучшему

Comment: если бы я знал ответы на "почему, плюсы, минусы" я бы написал, но т.к. с ораклом я не знаком, то это всего лишь комментарий.

Comment: @teran согласен. просто не чувствую что кто то ответит

Comment: А что такое "sequence table"? Где вы этот термин взяли?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Почему, например, в Oracle SQL нет понятия AUTO_INCREMENT?

Есть, [2.1.6.3 IDENTITY Columns](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12101.htm#NEWFT155), и даже называется в соответстви с ANSI стандартом:

> Table columns have been enhanced to support the American National Standards Institute (ANSI) SQL keyword IDENTITY.
>   This provides a standards based approach to the declaration of automatically incrementing columns simplifying application development and making the migration of DDL to Oracle simpler.

Было введено в релизе 12.1.0.1, дата выпуска 2014. Что же всё таки в те времена изменилось?

```
create table t1 (id number generated always as identity, item varchar2 (32));
insert into t1 (item) values ('first item');
select * from table (dbms_xplan.display_cursor);

----------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name          | Cost  |
----------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT         |               |     1 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL | T1            |       |
|   2 |   SEQUENCE               | ISEQ$$_120741 |       |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Как видно, при вставке используются всё те же последовательности (*sequences*), которые будут соданы  автоматически (неявно) и получат сгенерированные имена.

---

Говорить о плюсах/минусах лучше в рамках конкретной задачи с конкретными требованиями, но всё таки несколько замечаний:

- "Explicit is better than implicit" (ц) - явное всегда лучше неявного.
- В [этой статье](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1#Performance) можно посмотреть сравнение проиводительности и взять на заметку.
- `IDENTITY` колонки имют ряд ограничений, и это может [вывать некоторые "неудобства"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/921589/217579).